# Load Image from server and diaplay in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview

After parsing JSON array I'm getting image path How can I download that image and set it in list view.

```
 JSONObject iobject = aJson.getJSONObject(0);
 JSONObject imgObject =  iobject.getJSONObject("img_update");
 String img = imgObject.getString("0");
```

Here in string 'img' am getting image path
How can I set it to a imageview in list
what is simple and efficient solution for displaying those images in my android app as there will be hundreds of images.

following is my code in adapter class to set that image.There might be some error as its not working I read some tutorials related to this .

```
                if(image != null) {
                String img_path = "http://192.168.2.102/bootstrap/userapp_server/" +                   evnt.getEventImg();
                File imgFile = new  File(img_path);
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);  
                }
```

Comment: have you tried anything to set image in listview or you had searched related this ?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFC_enIN613IN613&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=set%20image%20url%20in%20imageview%20android)?

Comment: Do google search before you post any question, check if similar type of question had already been asked. And there are many libraries and there documentation available on net for doing your work.

Comment: where you had added this code to fetch image?

Comment: in my custom adapter class

Comment: are you getting exception like FileNotFound/IO Exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use universal image loader liabrary for loading image from server they provided good implementation for loading and caching image.
Find it [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)